# A nearest neighbour when edge costs are asymmetric, some doubts

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm, nearest-neighbor, knn

*To clarify my post, I have edited it based on comments.*

I was thinking how to implement a nearest neighbour search *efficiently* when edge costs are asymmetric. I'm thinking a range of cities something like from 100 to 12000.

In more detail, as an example, there's a cost **COST<sub>1</sub>** on travelling from city **A** to city **B**, e.g. by foot, and a cost **COST<sub>1</sub>/10** to travel from **B** to **A**, e.g. by train. In other words, the problem I see here is that if I have an asymmetric matrix **C** representing costs between travelling cities and I select one point **A**, how could discover *efficiently*, say, three nearest neighbouring cities **B<sub>1</sub>**, **B<sub>2</sub>** and **B<sub>3</sub>** in terms of travelling cost? I would like to run the queries repeatedly. Preprocessing time, if not huge, is all right.

The efficiency pondering let me to thinking something like a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), which faciliates for finding *k* nearest neighbours in *O(lg(n))* time when costs between cities are *symmetric*. This is the snag with just basic k-d tree in my case as the travelling costs aren't in general the same in both directions between any two cities. The gist of the matter seems to be then, how could I do something like k-nearest neighbours in asymmetric case?

To remedy the aforementioned symmetry assumption, I thought that instead of just one tree, I have two trees constructed so that the costs are calculated in both directions, and then I run a search through both trees. Then I became to wonder, does anyone know if there's already something specifically for the purpose of asymmetric costs and/or would using two trees as an idea be totally astray?

It also may be k-d trees in two dimensions isn't necessarily the most fit solution. So pointers to other data structures and algorithms are welcome too. Especially if someone has practical experience regarding my problem size. Wikipedia lists [quite a bunch of approaches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#See_also), and maybe even approximate solution is good for what I'm trying to do (this is for a smallish game for learning purposes).

Comment: I added tags for languages I'm most familiar with, but any pseudocode will do. I wonder also, would it be appropriate to include Weka as a tag? As those familiar with may perhaps be familiar with this problem domain.

Comment: Why not using an adjacency matrix in which you can store different values?

Comment: What is the input representation? You seem to be describing an adjacency list - and then nearest neighbor search is just running a few steps of the dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: @AquilaRapax, you can assume the data is stored in adjacency matrix and now I would like to preprocess it to facilitate efficient nearest neighbour finding.

Comment: @maniek, Yes, adjacency list would be all right. But what I would like to do is to pick an arbitrary city and find some of its nearest neighbours in terms of travelling cost. As I'd like to this repeteatedly, I'd prefer it to be efficient.

Comment: @maniek, I have to investigate if Dijikstra lends for the kind of approach I'm after. Let's see. :)

Answer (score 1):

For each point you need to calculate costs for all available travel types(foot,travel,..), lead to one unit,compare and get min. And this cost you can use in search algorithms.